Matter motion sensor for Google home household?
I have several lutron caseta light switches and Google homes. I want to add some motion sensors. I have a lutron sensor that seems to work but I want something that integrates with Google home so I can use it in the Google home script editor so I can create custom automations (like motion during the day is full lights, motion at night is partial lights etc)
The script editor theoretically lets you use motion sensors as a trigger but despite a lot of research, I can't seem to find a good matter motion sensor. I'm seeing mixed things about whether they really support matter or whether they require a hub to support matter or if they even work as advertised.
Does anyone have any recommendations on what would work?

What Google Home devices do you have? From what I can read (on the device specs pages), only the Google Nest Hub 2nd gen and Google Nest Hub Max have support for 802.15.4. For battery life reasons, I expect any (battery powered) Matter motion sensors to use that rather than Wi-Fi, so if none of your hubs supports it, you would need a bridge of some kind anyway. No idea if there are any "native" Matter motion sensors on the market though (there are Zigbee sensors which can be made Matter-compatible through their respective bridge/hub).

It might be first generation but i'd rather spend the money buying an updated nest hub than a bridge if possible. thanks for the input, sounds like I might need some sensor/bridge anyway. but beyond that I still want one that is supported in Google home automations if possible.

Before I go down this path and check if it is even possible, I'll ask: Are you able (willing) to reprogram the processors of IOT devices? Then solder together sensors and COTS IOT switches? If so, a possible answer my be to use firmware from the Tasmota project together with COTS PIR sensors.

Interesting but too technical for me. Thanks.
